# how to remove Google Map API key invalid Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im **getting error** as invalid Google API key error.

The page is unable to display a google Maps element. The provided Google Api key is invalid or this site isnt authrozied to use it. Error Code invalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError.

Following is the script in head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAmo6D4JJMMv-HIDDENHIDDENHIDDEN"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMapView'), mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

There is no referrer added so far as im trying only in localhost. Browser KEY

How to resolve the error

Comment: @scaisEdge how to resolve the error and make google map api work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it working by enabling the few more google map API.

[image: IMg]